# Grails 2.3.0 memory error with webflow

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

Since my application has been upgraded to grails 2.3.0, the webflow plugin (version 2.0.8.1) triggers an OutOfMemoryError error and a "method name must not be null" after a webflow action.

**Stack error:**

```
2013-09-14 00:39:10,574 ERROR [ClosureInvokingAction] - Exception occured invoking flow action: GC overhead limit exceeded
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:430)
2013-09-14 00:39:10,575 DEBUG [SessionBindingConversationManager] - Unlocking conversation 1
2013-09-14 00:39:10,584 ERROR [[grails]] - Servlet.service() for servlet grails threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:430)
2013-09-14 00:39:10,585 DEBUG [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - SecurityContext is empty or anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
2013-09-14 00:39:10,585 DEBUG [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2013-09-14 00:39:10,585 ERROR [[default]] - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/UbiCloud] threw exception [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:430)
```

**Followed by the webflow error:**

```
Method name must not be null. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method name must not be null
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.retrieveAction(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

**The webflow state:**

```
billingOrder {
            on("requestPayment") {
                // set local props
                def profile = flow.profile
                def pid = profile.id
                def service = flow.service
                def orders = flow.orders
                def email = conversation.email

                // subscription dates
                def today = new Date()
                def endOfSubscription = today + 365

                // billing create
                flow.billing = new Billing(
                        orders:orders,
                        profile:profile,
                        packcode:orders?.packcode,
                        creationdate:today,
                        name:profile?.name,
                        firstname:profile?.firstname,
                        address:params?.billing?.address,
                        postalcode:params?.billing?.postalcode,
                        town:params?.billing?.town,
                        country:params?.billing?.country, // TODO: check phone locale
                        tvanumber:params?.billing?.tvanumber,
                        paymentmode:PAY_MODE,
                        currency:CUR_MODE,
                        paymentterms:params?.billing?.paymentterms,
                        termsapproved:params?.billing?.termsapproved,
                        autorenewal:true,
                        newcontact:false,
                        active:false,
                        creditcardtype:params?.billing?.creditcardtype,
                        cardno:params?.billing?.cardno.trim(),
                        ed:params?.billing?.ed,
                        cvc:params?.billing?.cvc
                        )

                // process amount terms
                def billing = flow.billing
                if (billing.paymentterms == MONTH_MODE) {
                    billing.amount = orders.amountmonth
                } else if (billing.paymentterms == YEAR_MODE) {
                    billing.amount = orders.amountyear
                } else {
                    log.error "[STORE] No payment terms defined"
                }

                // profile fields
                profile.phone=params?.profile?.phone
                profile.mobilephone=params?.profile?.mobilephone
                profile.companyname=params?.profile?.companyname
                profile.sirencode=params?.profile?.sirencode

                // update technical contact
                service.temail=params?.service?.temail


                }
                if (!billing.validate() || !profile.validate() || !orders.validate() || !service.validate()) {
                    if(!billing.creditcardtype){
                        flash.messagecc = "store.billing.cc"
                    } else if(!billing.termsapproved){
                        flash.message = "store.billing.approveterms"
                    }
                    [billing:billing,orders:orders,profile:profile,service:service,orders:orders,rpid:rpid]
                    error()
```

**The bug comes from the grails chemistry to validate billing object, which results in Overflow error sometimes and "method name must not be null" in any case. 
No constraints or field have been added since the migration from grails 2.2.4 to grails 2.3, I suppose there must be a change in the the domain validation object or in the webflow process. 
Of course the billing domain object is serializable and beforeValidate() is transient.**

Comment: Are you running in forked JVM?

Comment: I've tried in and out forked JVM... same result

Comment: Nobody can help for a clue ?

Comment: how is your vm configured? heapsize and so on

Comment: JAVA_OPTS "-server -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"

Comment: Without JAVA_OPTS: `code` Exception occured invoking flow action: null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:711)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:554)
        ...
`code`

Comment: Well, i suppose the webflow plugin is not yet fully reliable for grails 2.3, or could be the databinding of the billing object in the flow ? Please help..

Comment: After some investigation i have found in grails doc " Do not attempt to flush the session within an event (such as with obj.save(flush:true)). Since events are fired during flushing this will cause a StackOverflowError." But here the pb appears on validation phase (billing.validate() ... Still stuck with that, but i'm not sure about webflow's session management

Comment: Still stucked with this error, probably related to grails webflow plugin. Please HELP